# "She always sees..." or "She is always seeing..."

Tags: meaning, differences, present-tense, sense-verbs, tenses

> - She always sees things that don't exist.
> - She is always seeing things that don't exist.

In the first sentence we use verb "to see" in the present simple tense. In the second sentence, verb "to see" in the present progressive, unusual for verbs that express forms of sense perception. Are both sentences correct and interchangeable?  Any subtle difference in meaning between them?

Comment: They're both correct, and interchangeable. I think there are subtle differences but an explanation is beyond my descriptive talents. Besides, it's time for me to get something to eat. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence expresses the speaker's opinion, it suggests an annoyance or irritability at the frequency with which the woman *is seeing* non-existent things. The present progressive tense is used when we mention the *activity*, and with many senses we can use this structure.

> 1. A: What are you doing?
>      B: I'm **tasting** this stew. I think it needs a bit more salt. What do you think?
> 2. A: Where's he going?
>      B: He's **seeing** his new girlfriend. (In this instance *see* = *meet*)
> 3. A: Why is he always **touching** his hair like that?
>      B: Because he's either incredibly vain or terribly insecure. Your pick.
> 4. A: Why are you **smelling** that meat? You only bought it yesterday.
>      B: I'm sure it's gone off. Here, have a sniff.
> 5. A: We're **hearing** all sorts of awful stories about the new neighbours.
>      B: It's just idle gossip, they're perfectly fine people.

Now is the *present simple* tense and the *progressive tense* always interchangeable?    No, it isn't. Compare:

1. A: What do you **do**?
   B: *I **taste*** wine for a living.
2. A: What are you looking for?
   B: My glasses. I can't **see** a thing without them.
3. A: If I told you once, I told you a hundred million times. *Don't touch* the DVDs with your grubby fingers.
   B: Sorry...
4. A: They say *dogs can **smell*** cancer.
   B: Really? I never knew.
5. A: *Can you **hear*** it? There's a noise downstairs.
   B: It's nothing. Now go back to sleep.

John Lawler in an answer posted a succinct explanation on [volitional](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105098/taste-is-to-flavor-as-touch-and-sight-are-to-what/105101#105101) and [non-volitional verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76005/correct-usage-of-see-vs-watch/76022#76022)

**Hearing**: You *listen* to something on purpose, but you can *hear* it by accident.
**Vision**: You *look* at something on purpose, but you can *see* it by accident.
Verbs for the other three senses don't vary; you can *smell*, *taste*, or *touch*/*feel* on purpose or not.

Therefore with non-volitional senses such as sight and hearing, we often use *can* and the verb remains in the present simple, the progressive tense is more common with things we do on purpose.

---

Without going into greater detail, I find that [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Present_progressive) explains well some of the differences between the *present simple* and *continuous*

> **Progressive**
>
> Verbs of mental state, sense perception and similar (*know*, *believe*, *want*, *think*, *see*, *hear*, *need*, etc.) are generally used without progressive aspect, although some of them can be used in the progressive to imply an ongoing, often temporary situation (*I am feeling lonely*), or an activity (*I am thinking about a problem*). See also *can*
>
> [...]
>
> **Present progressive**
>
> The *present progressive* or *present continuous* form combines
>   *present tense* with *progressive* aspect. It thus refers to an action or event conceived of as having limited duration, taking place at the
>   present time. It consists of a form of the simple present of *be*
>   together with the *present participle* of the main verb.
>
> We **are *cooking*** the dinner now.   This often contrasts with the
>   *simple present*, which expresses repeated or habitual action (We ***cook*** dinner every day). However sometimes the *present continuous* is used with *always*, generally to express annoyance about a
>   habitual action:(emphasis mine)
>
> - You **are always *making*** a mess in the study.
>
> Certain stative verbs do not use the *progressive aspect*, so the
>   *present simple* is used instead in those cases

Comment: A rushed answer, but hope this helps!

Comment: Should have taken your time. After all the scolding (from several members) I got for rushing to pick a right answer a few days ago, I will certainly wait until I get four or five answers to choose from, as I had always done.

Comment: Finally caught up with this post, spent a bit of time over it. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Reading your previous comment, I'm a bit confused. Does this mean you *know* when there is a "right answer"? So is this answer "right" but you wanted to wait longer to in order to be certain, or you don't believe this answer is correct but you accepted it out of politeness?

Comment: Mari-LouA, To be frank with you: I've asked 132 questions so far and most of the times I didn't know the answer or I wasn't sure about it. There were a few instances, however, when I did know the answer. One would certainly ask why I posted them. The main objective of this site is to build a Q&A data-bank about the English language, so I've been led to believe. I thought those questions would make good contributions if they were answered correctly, and I usually got very good answers as in ....

Comment: .... as in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195964/is-there-a-word-to-describe-the-kind-of-sentence-where-one-uses-ones-own-point. AND and english.stackexchange.com/questions/209789/… Other times I waited a few weeks and, as nobody gave a right answer, I answered it myself (though I don't like and avoid doing that) as in english.stackexchange.com/questions/195453/… That must have happened about 5 times out of 132 questions. And what I really wanted was to have somebody giving the right answer. As for your answer to "she Always sees...", I never accept an answer out of politeness.

Comment: A good answer has to be convincing and, more often than not, showing references. In this specific case I was waiting for a second and third answer and ended up by forgetting to revisit the page. I hope I have clarified it for you. Regards

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong in posting an answer, if nobody has come up with a satisfactory one.  I've answered my own questions when I saw it was either about to be closed,(wild act of desperation!) or because a good answer prompted me where to search for a better/more complete answer. Sometimes I've posted users' comments when they have refused my appeals to write a post of their own own. Of course I always given credit when that has happened.