# 'watch her run' vs 'watch her running'

Tags: phrase-usage, participles, bare-infinitive, nonfinite-clause-complementation

**QUESTION 1**
I'm trying to figure out the seemingly subtle difference(s) between a sentence modified by a bare infinitive and one modified by a participle phrase. What do you get out of these:

1. I *watched* her **run** across the bridge --> *verb of perception* followed by **bare infinitive**
2. I watched her **running across the bridge** --> **participle phrase**

I don't get why and when I should choose a bare infinitive over a participle phrase.

**QUESTION 2**
Also, 'watch' is a verb of perception, isn't it, similar to 'see'. [I have been reading this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76005/correct-usage-of-see-vs-watch)- I'm not sure if that explained the differences between watch and see, though; I might or might not have missed it.

Comment: The first suggests you watched the whole action while the second suggests you watched part of the action, (while the action was taking place).

Comment: @Josh61 Necessarily so? Source?

Comment: Lucie, for one, please capitalize appropriately, esp., first person pronoun at all times. Please take help in preparing the question well for grammar and format. Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry about that. I can see why not capitalising must be so annoying on a grammar site :3