# What tense is used for "go" in "you see it go away"?

Tags: tenses, sense-verbs, bare-infinitive, nonfinite-clause-complementation

I understand it's not the present tense, else it would be "goes". Is the sentence grammatically correct? If so, does it mean "you are seeing that it is going away"?

Comment: It looks no more than a simple present to me. Why wrack the brains?

Comment: @Kris The OP has already explained that it cannot be present tense - it has no third person /s/ inflection.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, when I read the title alone, my interpretation was of an imperative sense.  I envisioned someone annoying the speaker for a demonstration, the speaker finally relenting, ending with an exasperated, "(There.) You see it, (now) go away!"

Comment: @cobaltduck to avoid this double meaning, the example sentence could be "you see it go up and down"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Heard me \[infinitive\]" vs. "heard me \[present participle\]"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle). The title of [watch her run vs watch her running](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224372/watch-her-run-vs-watch-her-running) seems a closer match, but this was closed as a duplicate of the former.

Comment: Notice that one would say "You saw her go away" not "You saw *she go away*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbs of perception (see, hear, notice, etc.) are followed by an unmarked infinitive — technically a present infinitive, but the past infinitive can't be used in this construction — or a present participle. I saw him go. I saw him going. The difference is a slight emphasis either on the action as a whole (infinitive) or as a progressive activity one observes (present participle). Though in the objective case, "him" is actually the subject of the infinitive "go." https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/britisch-grammatik/verb-patterns/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing

Comment: See also: my comment at OP.  This link is more direct: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-verbs/verbs-basic-forms