# watch vs see depends on tense?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, verbs

I understand the difference between **watch** and **see** and that's not what this question is about. My question is why does the choice seem to be driven by tense at times? Consider the following examples:

> I saw this movie last night.
>
> I will see this movie next weekend.
>
> I have never seen this movie.
>
> I am watching this movie right now.

As you can see, it's the same action in different tenses and yet **see** seems a better fit when it's in the past tense or future whereas **watch** sounds better in the present tense. I just want to understand what drives this. To add to the confusion, there's this:

> I was watching the movie.

This one takes a **watch** despite being in the past tense. I know it seems stupid to think of **watch** vs. **see** as a tense-driven choice because no grammar book ever said that. But the pattern is hard to ignore, no?

Comment: Why do you think it seems better depending on tense? I find "I'm going to watch that movie next weekend" and  "I'm going to see that movie next weekend" to both be perfectly acceptable... similarly, "I watched that movie last night" and "I saw that movie last night" are both fine. Do you have any sources that say one is preferred over another or is this purely your personal opinion?

Comment: I already made it very clear in the question that it's what the pattern *seems* to me like. I am not saying it's a rule that I should furnish a citation for it. My question is why does the same action sound better with **watch** in one sentence (which is in one tense) and with **see** in another (in another tense).

Comment: Because one of the rules of SE is that you need to show your effort and your research. Also, this is just your opinion and I'm stating that your opinion is unfounded... which means you need to support your opinion with facts.

Comment: My question is why *watch* seems a better fit in one example and *see* in another, when the only difference between the examples is of their tense. No rule says this is a tense driven thing and yet that's what it looked like which is why the question. Thank you for being so useful. I'll wait for someone who can contribute.

Comment: *I'll **watch** this movie on video tonight, even though I **saw** it in the cinema last year* is perfectly normal English. The ***watch/see*** distinction is similar to ***listen to/hear*** (the first implies *volition* much more than the second). That's why we normally say *I'm **listening to** a great song on the radio* (because as with ***watching** a movie*, it's a deliberate act, and we'd like to think we're in control of whatever we're doing at any given moment). But if you saw a movie or heard a song in the past, maybe it's just something you happened to do (or that happened to you).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That makes perfect sense. Could you post your comment as an answer so I could accept it and close the thread? Thank you.

Comment: @TheLearner: I'm sure there are others who could explain it much better than me, but if I was going to take the time, I'd amend [this previous answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/76022/2637) and cite it as a duplicate. Your question is essentially a specific minor detail arising out of the basic distinction between the two verbs (perhaps with a small element of "idiomatically established" preference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct usage of "see" vs. "watch"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76005/correct-usage-of-see-vs-watch)

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/do-you-watch-a-movie-or-see-a-movie?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, and this is only speculation, the present continuous tense **be+see+ing** is generally avoided in affirmations such as

> I'm seeing *Alien 4* tonight

and

> He's seeing a film at this moment.

The verb **see** also means to **meet someone**, and said aloud without any previous context, it might be understood that there's an appointment to meet up with someone called Alien, or they are dating someone called Film. I know it's unlikely, as we are all equipped with common sense and personal experiences, but the first two structures do sound a *little* odd nevertheless, whereas I don't find any ambiguity in the following example:

> We were seeing a movie when suddenly there was a loud noise.

The structure ***be + Verb + ing*** expresses volition, and  there is no significant difference, in terms of volition, between “I'm seeing a play” and “I'm watching a play”, the latter being only preferable if referring to a television broadcast.

Having said that, the present participle ***seeing*** **+ a movie** often follows a preposition, and the main verb *like*. In the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like%20seeing%20a%20movie%2Cafter%20seeing%20a%20movie%2Cof%20seeing%20a%20movie%2Care%20seeing%20a%20movie%2Cwere%20seeing%20a%20movie&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clike%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc1) chart below,  the clear frontrunner is **after seeing a movie** with *of seeing a movie* and *like seeing a movie* not far behind.

[image]

The results shown with the verbs *are* and *were*  seem to confirm that native speakers tend to avoid the progressive tense with **see a movie**. This ambiguity, which I mentioned earlier, is easier to eliminate in print and with context, but maybe this infrequency of usage compared to *watching a movie*, is down to idiomaticity and little else.

[image]
(*Watching a movie* is represented in blue, while *seeing a movie* is in red.)

If we compare the following results with ***to see a movie***, [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watching+a+movie%2Cto+see+a+movie%2Clike+seeing+a+movie%2Cafter+seeing+a+movie%2Cof+seeing+a+movie%2Care+seeing+a+movie%2Cwere+seeing+a+movie&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwatching%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20see%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20seeing%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0) produces the following chart.

[image]

Comment: I've seen your charts in a few answers and absolutely love them. How are you generating these?

Comment: @BrettAllen hello :) Erm...if you look at the url address, delete the part where it says "graph": `..ngrams/graph?content...` and replace it with the word "chart", i.e. `..com/ngrams/chart?content=like...` you should see only the graph chart, save the image on your computer's hard disk and upload it using the editor tools available. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I'm colorblind and totally didn't realize "Ngram" was a link!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, FumbleFingers answered:

> *I'll **watch** this movie on video tonight, even though I **saw** it in the cinema last year* is perfectly normal English. The ***watch/see*** distinction is similar to ***listen to/hear*** (the first implies *volition* much more than the second). That's why we normally say *I'm **listening to** a great song on the radio* (because as with ***watching*** a movie, it's a deliberate act, and we'd like to think we're in control of whatever we're doing at any given moment). But if you saw a movie or heard a song in the past, maybe it's just something you happened to do (or that happened to you).

And then followed that up with:

> I'm sure there are others who could explain it much better than me, but if I was going to take the time, I'd amend [this previous answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76022/2637) and cite it as a duplicate. Your question is essentially a specific minor detail arising out of the basic distinction between the two verbs (perhaps with a small element of "idiomatically established" preference).

Comment: Mostly OK,  but the medium matters too. You generally only **see** movies _in the theater_, and **watch** them _on TV_.