# has some problem with my english

Tags: grammatical-number

1. Why we used " see a movie theater " instead of " watch a movie theater " ?
   2 . And which one of this are right " I want to see a film on TV everyday " or " I want to watch a film on TV everyday " ?

Comment: 'I have some/a problem with my English teacher' is unacceptable as a peeve.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cited sentences are correct, although they carry different meanings. Let's analyze them.

> See a movie theater

This one means you simply saw a movie theater, e.g. when you were walking down the street and passed it without being particularly concentrated on it.

> watch a movie theater

This one would mean that you deliberately stood in front of it to, let's say, admire its facade.

Which one of these two was correct depends on the context, but both are grammatically correct.

---

> I want to see a film on TV every day*
>
> I want to watch a film on TV every day

These two are almost the same, but seeing a movie typically involves going somewhere (e.g. movie theater) to do so. 'Watch a movie', on the other hand, indicates that you're staying at home. It's actually already been answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/do-you-watch-a-movie-or-see-a-movie). I'd personally go for 'see'.

*It's spelled 'every day' not 'everyday'

Comment: Considering that “on TV” is part of the sentence, did you mean that you’d personally go for _watch_? “I want to see a film on TV every day” doesn’t sound like a statement about what you want to spend your afternoons doing, but rather like a visionary in the early days of television describing his determination that one day there should be at least one film shown on TV every day.